# iOS dateFromString with CST does not work on the device

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I need to convert `NSString` `@"2014-02-26 16:56:03 -06:00 CST"` to `NSDate`. Tried `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz zzz"` with no luck. I think issue is in `zzz` `zzz` part.

Here is my code:

```
NSString *string = @"2014-02-26 16:56:03 -06:00 CST";
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
df.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz zzz";
NSDate *date = [df dateFromString: string];
```

**Date is nil only when using device**. On simulator all is ok.

Comment: Put here the code you tried

Comment: what format you try getting ? add some code .

Comment: @M.Y. hey i update my answer please check it hope it work  :)

Comment: "CST" will change or not?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get the correct date value on the device but I had to make a workaround.
Basically, if the time zone abbreviation (e.g. `"CST"`) is in the string the date formatter cannot parse the date. I looked into `Apple's` docs and had a look into [Unicode Technical Standard #35](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns). However I couldn't find a pattern that would work.

The workaround for this is to remove the time zone abbreviation. Then everything works as expected.

```
NSString *string = @"2014-02-26 16:56:03 -06:00 CST";
NSMutableArray *components = [[string componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] mutableCopy];

// Remove the time zone abbreviation.
[components removeLastObject];
string = [components componentsJoinedByString:@" "];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZZ";

NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString: string];

NSLog(@"Date: %@", date);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this would help u，if the NSString `@"2014-02-26 16:56:03 -06:00 CST"` format is fix, no matter whether it's CST of others,all fine:

```
    NSString *inDateStr = @"2014-02-26 16:56:03 -06:00 CST";
    NSString *dateStr = [dateStr substringToIndex:26]; // 2014-02-26 16:56:03 -06:00
    NSString *zoneStr =[dateStr substringFromIndex:27]; // CST
    NSDateFormatter*dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:zoneStr]];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss Z"];
    NSDate *outDate = [dateFormat dateFromString: dateStr];
```

Comment: Setting timeZone of NSDateFormatter doesn't matter, in case of CST at least

Comment: @M.Y. ok,if timeZone doesn't matter,both answers all can get the NSDate,@reecon answer better for the not fix NSString,my answer for the change timeZone and fix NSString format.